# React Exercise: Build a dynamic list application

Tags: react.js, jsx

**Task Description:**

- Create a div-element and take control over it using a Vue-Instance.
- Print an array of hobbies into the div-element. Provide some default 
  hobbies.
- Add a 'New Hobby' button and a text-input element. So that the user
  can add additional hobbies.
- When a hobby list-item is clicked, it shall be removed from the list.
- Add a "Hobby deleted"-paragraph which is only shown when a hobby-item
  has been deleted at least one time.
- Above the list of hobbies add a hobby-counter which shows the current
  count of hobby-items.
- Style the hobby-list depending on whether you have more or less then 
  3 hobbies in the list.
- Outsource your hobbies (the list-item elements) into a component (so 
  that it becomes re-usable).

**The source-code of my solution:**

```
// ----- index.js ----------
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// --------- App.js ----------
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Hobbies } from './Hobbies';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Hobbies />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

// ------------ Hobbies.js --------------
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { HobbyItem } from './HobbyItem';

class Hobbies extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            hobbies: [
                'Reading',
                'Sport',
                'Music',
                'Chess',
                'Cooking'
            ],
            deleted: false
        }
    }

    addHobby(event) {
        let currentHobbies = this.state.hobbies;
        let textBox = event.target.previousElementSibling;

        if (textBox.value) {
            currentHobbies.push(textBox.value);
            textBox.value = '';

            this.setState({
                hobbies: currentHobbies
            });
        }
    }

    removeHobby(event) {
        let currentHobby = event.target.textContent;
        let updatedHobbies = this.state.hobbies.filter((hobby) => {
            return currentHobby !== hobby;
        });

        this.setState({
            hobbies: updatedHobbies
        });

        !this.state.deleted && this.setState({
            deleted: true
        });
    }

    render() {
        let cssHobbyItem = 'hobby-item';
        let cssCounter = 'more-three';
        let hobbyItems = this.state.hobbies.map((hobby, i) => {
            return <li onClick={this.removeHobby.bind(this)}
                className={cssHobbyItem}
                key={cssHobbyItem + i}>{hobby}</li>;
        });
        let hobbiesLength = this.state.hobbies.length;

        if (hobbiesLength < 3) {
            cssCounter = 'less-three';
        } else if (hobbiesLength === 3) {
            cssCounter = 'equal-three';
        }

        return (
            <div className="hobbies-list">
                <nav className="nav-add">
                    <input type="text" id="input-add" />
                    <button id="new-hobby"
                        onClick={this.addHobby.bind(this)}>New Hobby</button>
                </nav>
                <p>{this.state.deleted && 'Hobby Deleted!'}</p>
                <p className={cssCounter} ><b>Count of Hobbies:
                </b> {this.state.hobbies.length}</p>
                <ul>
                    {hobbyItems}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export { Hobbies };

// --------- HobbyItem.js ---------------
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class HobbyItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <li></li>
        );
    }
}

export { HobbyItem }
```

[**Working Live-Demo**](http://n-or.de/apps/react-hobbies-list/)

Is it all done in a good way and manner?

What would you do differently and why?

Looking forward to reading your comments and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I know sqat about `react.js`.*
I only have some minor nitpicks.

---

When the body of an anonymous function is a single line,
instead of `... => { return value; }`, you can write more compactly as `... => value`, for example here:

```
let updatedHobbies = this.state.hobbies.filter((hobby) => currentHobby !== hobby);
```

---

Although this works, I think it's an unusual writing style,
and it would be better to spell it out as an `if` statement:

> ```
> !this.state.deleted && this.setState({
>     deleted: true
> });
> ```

---

When I saw this code, it made me curious what happens for other values of `hobbiesLength`, that is, what would be in an `else` block:

> ```
> if (hobbiesLength < 3) {
>     cssCounter = 'less-three';
> } else if (hobbiesLength === 3) {
>     cssCounter = 'equal-three';
> }
> ```

The answer to that is a couple of lines higher up:

> ```
> let cssCounter = 'more-three';
> ```

If you move this to the `else` block,
then all the possible values of `cssCounter` will become easily visible in one place, which will be easier to read and understand.